# Elementary Elliptic Curves

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elliptic-curves

So there is this question our professor gave us at the end of the lecture to think about and it goes:

Prove that $n$ is $t-$congruent iff the following:

**i)** Either both $\frac{n}{t}$ and $t^2+1$ are non zero rational squares.

**ii)** or the Elliptic curv: $C_{n,t}:y^2=\frac{x(x-\frac{n}{t})}{x+nt}$ has a rational point $(x,y)$ with $y \ne 0.$

How would I go about to solve this problem?

Comment: ...or the elliptic curve what?

Comment: Sorry edited the question, now does it make more sense?